# Only every 5th shape valid reading shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile

I have a shapefile of drycleaning facilities in Florida.  I am reading the file in Python using shapefile.py.  My problem is that while the first shape in the file appears correct, after that only every 5th shape is correct.  Four shapes in a row are extracted with an invalid type code (which should be between 0 and 31) and no point information.  Here is a section of the results:

```
Site Name (.record[1])               .shapeType  .points
------------------------------------ ----------- --------------------
Granda Dry Cleaners                  21          [[783897.335, 215901.765]]
Scotch Dry Cleaners                  1093131927  []
J C Cleaners                         -1191051264 []
Royal Palm Cleaners                  -1606317767 []
Moorings Plaza Dry Cleaners          1091081765  []
Classic Touch Cleaners               21          [[778662.429, 221265.968]]
The Drycleaner                       1093095627  []
Randolphs Alterations & Dry Cleaner  -1140719616 []
Pelican French Cleaners              1580547967  []
Town & Country Cleaners              1091080779  []
Discount Dryclean Outlet             21          [[768035.181, 188652.929]]
The Drycleaner Cleaners              1093104359  []
Sample Cleaners                      -1090387968 []
Parisian Cleaners                    -1468878813 []
Roberts Cleaners & Tailors           1091022843  []
```

(note: I cut down the precision on the points a bit to make them fit on a line).

The pattern appears to me to be regular — one "valid" record followed by four records with an invalid shapeType constant and no points.

I am a novice at shapefile processing.  Does these results suggest anything I may be doing incorrectly?

**Update**

The following code demonstrates the problem (it prints the shapeType and points columns described above):

```
from shapefile import Reader)
rdr = Reader('drycleaner_list')
for s in rdr.shapes():
   print s.shapeType, s.points
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to determine if the problem is with the shapefile.  Try loading the file using a true GIS tool such as QuantumGIS.  Once you are sure your SHP file is correct, post your code so we can see how you are using shapefile.py.  My guess is that the SHP file is incorrect in some way andn Quantum GIS will either fix it or tell you whats wrong.  Bonus:  QuantumGIS has python embeded as a plugin development tool.

**EDIT:**
I downloaded the file dryclean_apr12.shp from the Florida DEP.  According to the dbf data, there are 1423 records.  When I use your code snippet I get 1423 shapes all of shapetype=1  which indicates that each shape is a single point.

Therefore your code is correct, the issue has to be with the file.

I noticed in your sample data that the shapetype is 21 or a PointM  which is defined as

Position Field Value Type Number Order

```
Byte 0 Shape Type 21 Integer 1 Little
Byte 4 X X Double 1 Little
Byte 12 Y Y Double 1 Little
Byte 20 M M Double 1 Little
```

A Point is defined as

```
Position Field Value Type Number Order
Byte 0 Shape Type 1 Integer 1 Little
Byte 4 X X Double 1 Little
Byte 12 Y Y Double 1 Little
```

Either the Shapefile is corrupt or there is a bug in shapefile.py.

A Shapefile with PointM  has a layout of

```
IDDD
IDDD
IDDD
IDDD
IDDD
IDDD
```

If Shapefile is reading this as a Point (IDD)

Then the file is read as

```
IDD      Rec 1 Read OK
did      Rec 2 Error on Type
ddi      Rec 3 error on Type
ddd      Rec 4 error on Type
IDD      Rec 5 Read OK
```

Comment: The shapefile is published by the Florida DEP and displays correctly in Google Earth Professional (according to my colleague who obtained the file).  Code is just a couple of lines, I'll add it to question.